# Не получается использовать Telegram Login Widget в React-app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

У меня есть вот такой компонент для использования виджета:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class TelegramLoginButton extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { botName, size, requestAccess, showUserPic, callbackOnAuth } = this.props;
    window.TelegramLoginWidget = {
      callbackOnAuth: user => callbackOnAuth(user)
    };
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?2';
    script.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', botName || 'samplebot');
    script.setAttribute('data-size', size || 'large');
    script.setAttribute('data-request-access', requestAccess || 'write');
    script.setAttribute('data-userpic', !showUserPic);
    script.setAttribute('data-onauth', 'TelegramLoginWidget.callbackOnAuth(user)');
    script.async = true;
    this.instance.appendChild(script);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={component => this.instance = component}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TelegramLoginButton.propTypes = {
  callbackOnAuth: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  botName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(['small', 'medium', 'large']),
  requestAccess: PropTypes.oneOf(['write']),
  showUserPic: PropTypes.bool
};

export default TelegramLoginButton;
```

При его использовании вылазит вот такая ошибка:

> Refused to display
>   'https://oauth.telegram.org/embed/ld_notify_test_bot?origin=http%3A%2F%2Ftelegram.comments%3A8080&size=large&userpic=true&request_access=write'
>   in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-ancestors http://telegram.comments".

Само приложение крутится по адресу: http://telegram.comments:8080/ в настройках бота указан домен http://telegram.comments:8080/

В чем проблема? Домены свопадают, ни каких проблем быть не должно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виджет не работает, если порт отличен от 80-го.

Comment: @Pyramidhead - я не мог разобраться почему не работает виджет - нашел причину и написал ответ. Это ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Как ты решил эту проблему?